# CGAL 4.12's Lazy_exact_nt not exact?

Tags: cgal

The test function below works as expected with CGAL 4.9.1 but with CGAL 4.12 the computations are not exact. Any ideas what can cause the problem (more details below)?

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT dbl;
void test4()
{
    // 1. Create the smallest possible double and verify
    double smallDouble(1.0);
    while(smallDouble/2.0>0) smallDouble/=2.0;
    if(smallDouble/2.0==0) cout<<"can't divide smallDouble anymore, as expected"<<endl;

    // 2. Make it a dbl (K::FT)
    dbl a(smallDouble);

    // 3. Let b be even smaller ( smaller than the smallest double )
    dbl b(a/2.0);

    // 4. Show interval and try fit_in_double
    cout<<"a.approx()="<<a.approx()<<endl;
    cout<<"b.approx()="<<b.approx()<<endl;
    double d;
    if(CGAL::internal::fit_in_double(b,d))
    {
        cout<<"Yes, b fits in double d: "<<d<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Before b.exact(): b does not fit back into double (as expected)"<<endl;
    }

    // 5. Call exact and try fit_in_double again
    cout<<"\nCalling exact()"<<endl;
    b.exact();
    cout<<"a.approx()="<<a.approx()<<endl;
    cout<<"b.approx()="<<b.approx()<<endl;
    if(CGAL::internal::fit_in_double(b,d))
    {
        cout<<"Yes, after exact() b fits in double d: "<<d<<" - Huh, not as expected!"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"NOK after exact()"<<endl;
    }

    if(b<a) cout<<"b<a, as expected"<<endl;
        else cout<<"b >= a, not expected"<<endl;

    double c(to_double(b));
    cout<<"c="<<c<<endl;
    if(c==b) cout<<"c==b, not as expected"<<endl;
}
```

The output of CGAL4.9.1 is

```
can't divide smallDouble anymore, as expected
a.approx()=[4.94066e-324;4.94066e-324]
b.approx()=[0;4.94066e-324]
Before b.exact(): b does not fit back into double (as expected)

Calling exact()
a.approx()=[4.94066e-324;4.94066e-324]
b.approx()=[0;4.94066e-324]
NOK after exact()
b<a, as expected
c=0
```

The output of CGAL4.12 is

```
can't divide smallDouble anymore, as expected
a.approx()=[4.94066e-324;4.94066e-324]
b.approx()=[0;4.94066e-324]
Before b.exact(): b does not fit back into double (as expected)

Calling exact()
a.approx()=[4.94066e-324;4.94066e-324]
b.approx()=[4.94066e-324;4.94066e-324]
Yes, after exact() b fits in double d: 4.94066e-324 - Huh, not as expected!
b >= a, not expected
c=4.94066e-324
c==b, not as expected
```

Details: Ubuntu 18.04, gcc 7.3. I have used the script CGAL412/Scripts/scripts/cgal_create_cmake_script to create a CMakeLists.txt and thus the compiler options should be correct. CGAL4.12 has been compiled from source using

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/CGAL412  ../..
make
make install
```

Comment: Hmm, I rewrote the function that converts Gmpq to Interval_nt (using MPFR 3.*), and it looks like there is a bug...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in CGAL. Unless you also use MPFR directly yourself, you can easily work around it for this specific value by calling `mpfr_set_emin (-1073);` at the beginning of your program. However, it may not solve all such issues (we are also missing a call to mpfr_subnormalize), for instance for `Gmpq(DBL_TRUE_MIN)*3/2`. The safest would be to use the old code. For this, locate a test `#if MPFR_VERSION_MAJOR >= 3` in files Gmpq.h and mpq_class.h, and replace it with `#if 0`.
I filed this in [CGAL's github](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/3099) so we don't forget to fix it.